# How to input SpannableStringBuilder into Hashmap with looping

Tags: java, android, listview, hashmap

THIS MY CODE  :

```
for(int i = 0;i< cursor.getCount(); i++){

        String notes = Name[i];
        sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(notes);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("A", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("c", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        m = p.matcher(notes);
        m2 = p2.matcher(notes);


        while (m.find()){
            sb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)), m.start(), m.end(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        }
        while (m2.find()){
            sb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(255, 255, 0)), m2.start(), m2.end(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        }
```

My Question : How to put (sb) into hashmap, I want the content in my listview to have the color I have set up. With the color set in the span (String notes) above

```
        txtView.setText(sb);

        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("x1",ID[i]);
        map.put("x2",Name[i]);
        myList.add(map);

    }

    SimpleAdapter Adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myList, R.layout.mycustom_list,
            new String[] {"x1","x2"},
            new int[]{R.id.textID, R.id.textName});
```